# Where to put API key in react?

Tags: reactjs, api, http

I just started learning React technology. I've watched some videos on youtube. Now I want to fetch data from API, but when I access the end point,it returns an error : `missing API KEY in header`.
I wanted to know where should I put my API KEY

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup. Usually, `API KEYS`, token secrets or any type of configuration are set in environment variables.

As soon you set them, they are easily reached at `process.env.YOUR_API_KEY`. For webpack, please refer to `webpack.DefinePlugin` as:

`plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      YOUR_API_KEY: JSON.stringify('VALUE')
    }
  })
]`

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code where you're sending the request to the API. As the error message describes you need to put your API KEY in the request headers.

Something like this basically, but you need to check what key exactly you need to send for this endpoint.

`curl -H "X-API-KEY: xyz123abc" https://myapi.com/resources`